# How to use .AddRange in LiveCharts if X and Y are Lists?

Tags: c#, livecharts

I want to display temperature values with Live Charts.
For now I have this:

```
public class MeasureModel
{
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
List<string> time
List<Double> values
```

```
foreach (string date in time)
{
    ChartValues.Add(new MeasureModel
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse(time[i].ToString()),
        Value = double.Parse(values[i].ToString())
    });
}
```

When I add a measurement containing nearly 1k values, the time to load takes nearly 10 secs.
The website says I should use something like this:

```
var temporalCv = new double[1000];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    temporalCv[i] = 5;
}

var cv = new ChartValues<double>();
cv.AddRange(temporalCv);
```

But if I pass the `.AddRange` both variables as lists it cannot convert from `MeasureModel`to `Generic.IEnumerable<object>`
Does this mean I have to make the lists Enumerable?

If so, how?

Comment: What is `ChartValues`?

Comment: did you instantiate `List<MeasureModel> ChartValues = new List<MeasureModel>();` because I'm not getting any compiler errors or type issues

Comment: also where is the index `i` coming from in your `foreach` ?  Keep in mind it's not an increment `int` loop so you will need another way to get a unique index